# How to add tags in to FactoryGirl Topic object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have problem with FactoryGirl. I wrote simple forum app and add Tags functionality to topics. Everything works fine but I have problem with testing this feature.

This is my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    sequence(:name)       {|n| "Person #{n}"}
    sequence(:email)      {|n| "person_#{n}@forumapp.com"}
    password              "foobar92"
    password_confirmation "foobar92"
  end
  factory :forum do 
    name "Test Forum"
    description "Test Forum Description"
  end
  factory :tag do 
    name "Test"
  end
  factory :topic do 
    name "Test Topic"
    description "Test Topic Description"
    forum 
    user
  end
  factory :post do 
    content "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    topic
    user
  end
end
```

In my topic_pages_spec i'm doing something like this:

```
 let(:tag) {FactoryGirl.create(:tag)}
 let(:topic){FactoryGirl.create(:topic, forum: forum, user: user, tags: tag)}
```

My database schema for tags and topics looks like this:

```
create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id", using: :btree
  add_index "taggings", ["topic_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_topic_id", using: :btree

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "topics", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "forum_id",    null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id",     null: false
    t.string   "description"
  end
```

My topic model is:

```
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

tagging model:

```
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :topic
```

tag model:

```
  has_many :taggings   has_many :topics, through: :taggings
```

When i'm trying to run this spec i have the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: let!(:topic){FactoryGirl.create(:topic, forum: forum, user: user, tags: tag)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for #<Tag:0x000000078f7210>
     # ./spec/requests/topic_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't have any idea how to test this feature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `has_many :tags, through: :taggins` - it means that `Topic` expects an array of tags in method create. I am not sure if it works in your case (you have option `through`) but the error says that it tries to iterate by `tag` unsuccessfully.

Try add `[]`

```
let(:topic){FactoryGirl.create(:topic, forum: forum, user: user, tags: [tag])}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot but now i have next problem...
When I'm trying to testing link for this tag in topic show action i have error but everything should work fine...
    it {should have_link("test", href: tag_path(tag))} give the following error:
 expected #has_link?("test", {:href=>"/tags/1327"}) to return true, got false

Comment: it is necessary to debug. Maybe link's text is wrong, maybe smth else. I recommend to use method `save_and_open_page` (it seems to me gem `launchy` provides this method).